# What can you do with "running" hand weights?

Tags: weights

A while ago I asked whether [it was beneficial to run with hand weights](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6392/is-running-with-hand-weights-a-bad-idea). As a result, I pretty much stopped using them, and forgot all about them. Today I found my old hand weights in my closet, and so now my question is slightly different - what *do* people do with them? Is there some kind of exercise that is widely recommended?

[image]

Comment: Seeing how hand weights are a pretty specialized piece of equipment, I don't see how to miss-use them in a beneficial way. They would make for a very very awful and much too light dumbbell substitute, but other than that I can't think of anything exercise-related that wouldn't suffer from the same disadvantages as running with them.

Comment: Use them as a doorstop or paperweight, they are hocum imo

Comment: Stretching with them might be a good idea. Similar to the answer by @venite, but more dynamic. I have seen a few folks do this, but I have no idea on how common/beneficial it actually is.

Answer (score 1):

In our circuit training group we have some exercises that you could do with hand weights, like stretching out your arms like a 'T' and making slight rotating movements while holding the weights. This usually makes me want to cry in a minute or less, so I hope it's effective.

Answer (score 0):

The added weight would definitely aid your workout,These can be used for all sorts of mild to moderate exercises, You could wear them and jog on the treadmill, hence it would help you in balance and forearm and hand muscles. The alternative is that you hold small dumbbells in each hand, but that looks awfully awkward.
Enjoy your workouts!

Comment: In the discussion linked by Eyal, it has already been established that using the weights as intended might hurt the wrists and offers no other benefits. That's why he was asking for _other_ uses for these.